# Is there a way to avoid loops when adding to a list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, data-structures, collections

I was wondering a code like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(CustomObject co : objects) {
    list.add(co.getActualText());
}
```

Can it be written differently? I mean of course at some point there will be a loop but I am wondering if there is an API usage I am ignoring

Comment: it's called Clojure ;D  You can read about (conj) here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj

Comment: it's also called Scala, and Haskell, and… (insert name of any powerful programming language)

Answer (score 29):

If you use Java 8, you can take advantage of the Stream API:

```
List<String> list = objects.stream()
                           .map(CustomObject::getActualText)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: TBH IMHO this is actually unreadable for a simple task. This is not about your answer but about the Java approach itself

Comment: Not really agreeing Jim, it's also a matter of getting used to a new concept. Though in Scala it would be prettier with a simple val list = objects.map(_.getActualText)

Comment: The .NET people have LINQ for many years now and it is clear that it is a much better approach than list-building loops in almost all cases. I think the Java people just need to get around to have a shift in mentality here. This code is not unreadable by itself. It is unreadable to the inexperienced. This is a temporary state.

Comment: This is how it's done in the .NET world. I wish there were streams when I were using java.

Answer (score 20):

If you have Java 8, what about:

```
objects.forEach(item -> list.add(item.getActualText()));
```

Internally still a loop though.

EDIT a little Off-Topic: IMO This is the most readable and best solution. Why not just use a foreach you might ask. The answer: Because this way the collection chooses the best way to iterate over the items. For example, ArrayList does not use an iterator, because it knows better than you:

```
@Override
public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final E[] elementData = (E[]) this.elementData;
    final int size = this.size;
    for (int i=0; modCount == expectedModCount && i < size; i++) {
        action.accept(elementData[i]);
    }
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to add that I since have grown to the "functional" approach Konstantin Yovkov showed. The style feels very clean, even if it looks horrible and might perform badly in java

Answer (score 9):

Of course, Apache Commons and Guava also provide ways to avoid loops without using Java 8.

Commons [CollectionUtils.collect](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#collect%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29):

```
CollectionUtils.collect(objects, Transformer.invokerTransformer("getActualText"), list);
```

Guava [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29):

```
List<String> list = Lists.transform(objects, 
    new Function<CustomObject, String>() { 
        public String apply(CustomObject co) {
            return co.getActualText();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: In Java 8, the Guava example can be written much more concisely by replacing the anonymous class with a lambda: `Lists.transform(objects, (co) -> co.getActualText())`

Answer (score 6):

Although clearly a bit of a ridiculous suggestion: you could avoid loops by adding them recursively.

```
void add(List<? super String> receiver, CustomObject[] objects) {
  addRec(receiver, toAdd, 0, objects.length());
}

void addRec(List<? super String> receiver, CustomObject[] objects, int start, int end) {
  if (start + 1 == end) {
    receiver.add(objects[start].getActualText());
  } else if (start != end) {
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    addRec(receiver, objects, start, mid);
    addRec(receiver, objects, mid, end);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since O(n) operations really call for dynamically varying control flow (i.e. a loop), this was going to be my answer. It's a little trollish in an imperative language, but in a pure functional language, it's all you've got. +1.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can write the following as of Java 8:

```
MutableList<CustomObject> objects = ...
MutableList<String> result = objects.collect(CustomObject::getActualText);
```

With Java 5 - 7 you can use an anonymous inner class representing the SAM type [Function](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/block/function/Function.html) with the collect method.

```
MutableList<CustomObject> objects = ...
MutableList<String> result = objects.collect(new Function<CustomObject, String>() {
    public String valueOf(CustomObject object){
        return object.getActualText();
    }
});
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 3):

Using streams would be more idiomatic in Java 8, but if you like it to be closer to the conventional loop based approach you can use `forEach`:

```
objects.forEach(co -> list.add(co.getActualText()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve really good efficiency when copying a range of data between two types of lists that are unknown to each other, there must be a mechanism by which a "trusted" type can ask each to expose the backing array(s) associated with a range of elements, and then use a bulk-copy operation to move data from one to the other.  It would be possible to write such a class entirely in Java, by having a `GetArraySource` method pass to the constructor of a trusted `ArraySource` class an object it could use to request the backing array associated with a particular element (the return would include the backing array and the range of elements included therein).  The code wanting the copy would call `GetArraySource`, and pass the `ArraySource` returned thereby to the destination list's `CopyFromArraySource` method which could then ask the `ArraySource` to copy one or more ranges of items into its own backing array(s).

If `ArraySource` was a class supplied with Java, and Oracle documented exactly what it would do with arrays that it received, then it would be possible for types like `ArrayList` and `String` to expose their contents as an `ArraySource`, or accept outside data from an `ArraySource`, without improperly exposing their array to any code that might abuse it.

Unfortunately, unless Oracle incorporates such a thing into the Java distribution, support will probably be too sparse to be useful.  It does not good to have the source list support one such class, the destination support another, and the code wanting the copy operation a third.  All three classes need to support the same particular trusted-array-segment-copy-helper class.

Comment: I think you have something like C's memcopy in mind of the actual data. Right?

Comment: @Jim: I would expect that the bulk-copy operations in `Arrays` would probably be natively implemented using something roughly equivalent to `memcpy` once it determined that no object could exist in the source array which the destination array type couldn't hold [an attempt to e.g. bulk copy items from a `Cat[]` to an `Animal[]` could simply copy references directly, but going the other way it would be necessary to validate the type of each referenced object before copying the reference].