# Get sum of all mins and max from big input values

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

We are doing the following programming exercise: [Functions of Integers on Cartesian Plane](https://www.codewars.com/kata/559e3224324a2b6e66000046).

The task is to write three functions to get the sum of all min numbers between x and y (all the combinations), other function to sum all the max numbers between x and y, and a third one to have the sum of the previous ones.

We have written:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Funcij {

    public static BigInteger  sumin /*⬇️*/ (int n) {
        System.out.println("\nsumin n: "+n);
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for(int y=1; y<=n; y++){
      for(int x=1; x<=n; x++){
        sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.min(x,y)));  
      }
    }
    return sum;
    }
    public static BigInteger  sumax /*⏫*/ (int n) {
        System.out.println("\nsumax n: "+n);
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for(int y=1; y<=n; y++){
      for(int x=1; x<=n; x++){
        sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.max(x,y)));  
      }
    }
    return sum;
    }

    public static BigInteger  sumsum /*➕*/ (int n) {
        System.out.println("\nsumsum n: "+n);
    return sumin(n).add(sumax(n));
    }
}
```

However its execution time runs out (so then it fails the tests) for large input numbers.

How could we improve the code to avoid nested loops?

We have read to solve it by ourselves:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-valueof-method-in-java/
- [Is there a way to avoid loops when adding to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155970/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-loops-when-adding-to-a-list)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/
- [Get min and max value from this array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734130/get-min-and-max-value-from-this-array-of-hashes)
- [All values between min and max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746935/all-values-between-min-and-max)

Comment: Hint: look at the first few values for sumsum(1), sumsum(2), etc. They are 2, 12, 36, 80, 150, ... Can you find a pattern? Or, search for the sequence online. You need to use math to solve this, not just programming.

Answer (score 0):

For sumin:

Integer x is smaller than n-x other integers in the range `[1, n]`. Therefore it will contribute `x * (n - x) + x` to this sum (+x because we also add maximum between x and x). If you sum this expression for Xs from 1 to n you will get `n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6`. This last expression is exactly sumin.

Similarly for sumax each number will contribute exactly `x*x` and summing it up you get `n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`, which, again, will be exactly sumax.

These formulas will very fast for most inputs (but for REALLY big inputs you might want to use a multiplication algorithm faster than the default one)